# fread() deals with quoted zero-prefixed colum different from read.csv()

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I have a csv file with quoted numeric column such as "'0001',a\n'0002',b\n'0003',c", for fread(), the first column will be character but for read.csv() the 1st column will be numeric type. 
How can I make it work same as read.csv()?

Comment: No, read.csv does not read it as numeric, running `read.csv(text = "'0001',a\n'0002',b\n'0003',c", header=FALSE)`

Comment: Double posted: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2078

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type of the column through argument `colClasses`, e.g.

```
fread(..., colClasses = c("character", "character"))`.
```

Comment: quoted numeric column